# How to create a good ER model for this program (Questions about my ER model)

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I'm starting to build my application DataBase, and I'm really new to the this world, so I have a lot of doubts about my ER model and if it's entities and relationships are ok.

This is an application that calculate how much me and my friends profit in a videogame and saves all the data so we can check it later.
I'll explain it a bit so you can understand the ER model.

We want to save this data about every Hunt:

- Where the HUNT was (RESPAWN)
- How many people we were (1 to 4)
- The date of the HUNT
- How much everyone WASTE (Knight, Druid, Paladin, Sorcerer and the Total)
- The loot value
- The HUNT balance
- How many profit we did (each one of us)
- The amount of money everyone have to recieve (paying waste + profit -> TRANSFER)
- And if the HUNT is already paid or not

I'm already doing all the math and saving this data in a .txt file for the moment but I want to take the next step and build a decent database, and to make sure it's ok I'm asking you here if this model would be OK.

If some relationships are wrong or you think I should add more tables please tell me your opinion.

[image: ER model 1st version]

Thank you a lot

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to specify your specific technical concern.

Comment: I don't know how to define It. Maybe: How to design a good ER model for my application? I don't know how to specify my problem in the title, as it is a question about if this concrete model is correct.

Comment: This site is for narrowly-focused questions on a specific technical issue. If you cannot pinpoint such an issue, then this is not the right site for you. Seek a discussion site such as http://www.CodeRanch.com/

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help :D I'll ask there.